# UML - modeling drag'n'drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, uml

I am wondering how I could model the act of dragging and dropping in UML (class diagrams)

I've thought linking two classes with a relationship (the view and the element) but sounds like awkward, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to model the act of drawing UML diagrams (dragging and dropping elements in a class diagram) in UML? Or modelling dragging and dropping as an action in general?

If it's the general case. This sounds like a sequence diagram, or possible an activity diagram (although I think this might be less informative). Not really a class diagram, that's low level and structural not behavioral.

Comment: Thank you, I'll fall back to an activity diagram then

Comment: I don't know what your modelling here of course so without a little more explanation I can't be too specific. But a good rule of thumb here is usually, activity for flow of functionality (I say between use cases) and sequence for a use case or part of a use case. Your problem sounds like a single use case. But much of this is how you, and the team your trying to communicate the design to, feel comfortable. There are no strict rules in UML.

Comment: I would also say a sequence diagram